# 10 DOF gyro and accelerometer to x,y,z displacement

Tags: arduino-uno, gyroscope, imu

I have a 10 DOF sensor with wire outputs labeled "VIN", "GND", "SCL", and "SDA".  I would like to wire these into my arduino and ultimately obtain x, y, and z displacement.  This might sound like a simple problem for a veteran but I have gotten lost in the literature and code.  Where can I learn how to do this or is there a library that I can use?

Comment: Google "10 DOF IMU" should give you plenty of information. Here is a learning resource based on Adafruit products https://learn.adafruit.com/products/1604/guides

Comment: When asking a question here it is always appreciated if you include part numbers.  Or vendor web pages.  Guessing, SCL is a serial clock line and SDA is the serial data line.  So it sounds like you have a chip which talks over an I2C serial bus.  So you need the I2C Arduino library.  But, the real problem - what does the chip look like inside?  How many registers?  What do the bits mean in those registers?  How do you control this chip?  That's why you need a part number.

Comment: Step one: Read the number(s) on the chip(s). Step two: find libraries and tutorials for those chips.

Comment: I think this is it.  https://www.dfrobot.com/product-818.html

Comment: The link to the datasheets is at the bottom of this page, https://wiki.dfrobot.com/10_DOF_Mems_IMU_Sensor_V2.0_SKU__SEN0140, but I don't know what is relevant in my case.